# New to Swift and I am stuck on whether or not to use a switch or if statement

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I am currently learning Swift and I am practicing by making a simple app. The gist of the app is as follows - you click the colors in the segmented controls, and it changes the paint color in the bucket, depending on which colors are selected. This issue I am having is when I tap two of the colors (red and yellow for example) it is simply staying red. When I tap red and yellow, it should change the paint to orange. The only time the paint changes is when the same color is selected in both segmented controls. I know this is possible by using an if statement, but the instructor wants us to use a switch.

[image] 
This should be orange:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var paintBucket: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var firstColorSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var secondColorSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func mixColors(first: String, second: String) -> UIColor {

    switch (first, second) {
    case ("Red", "Red"):
        return UIColor.red
    case ("Red", "Yellow"), ("Yellow", "Red"):
        return UIColor.orange
    case ("Red", "Blue"), ("Blue", "Red"):
        return UIColor.purple
    case ("Yellow", "Yellow"):
        return UIColor.yellow
    case ("Yellow", "Blue"), ("Blue", "Yellow"):
        return UIColor.green
    case ("Blue", "Blue"):
        return UIColor.blue
    default:
        return UIColor.white
    }

}

@IBAction func colorSelected(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let firstSelection = firstColorSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

    let secondSelection = secondColorSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex


    switch firstSelection & secondSelection {

    case 0 & 0:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Red", second: "Red")

    case 0 & 1:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Red", second: "Yellow")

    case 0 & 2:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Red", second: "Blue")

    case 1 & 0:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Yellow", second: "Red")

    case 1 & 1:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Yellow", second: "Yellow")

    case 1 & 2:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Yellow", second: "Blue")

    case 2 & 0:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Blue", second: "Red")

    case 2 & 1:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Blue", second: "Yellow")

    case 2 & 2:

        paintBucket.backgroundColor = mixColors(first: "Blue", second: "Blue")

    default:

        break
    }


 }

}
```

Thank you in advanced for any help you can give me!

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your program, look carefully at how you use the switch() with different input values, realize what that ampersand really does....

Comment: Your entire second Switch statement is used to map numbers (`0`, `1` and `2`) to strings (`Red`, `Yellow`, and `Blue`). This is much more complex than it needs to be, because you have to define every possible pair. For 3 colours, that's 9 pairs! If you wanted a fourth colour, that shoots up to 16 pairs, then 25, ... It's not scalable.

Comment: Take a look at my approach to your code. I use enums, which I don't know if you have covered yet. Feel free to ask any follow up questions, and I'll be happy to explain. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/789d1fee5328899098763e1b81e47335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` argument is wrong, you have to switch on a tuple like in `mixColors`:

```
switch (firstSelection, secondSelection) {

case (0, 0):

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mixColors method looks good. You're using tuples for your switch statement, which is a good use of the power of the switch statement.

Your other case statement is wrong however. You should rewrite that to use tuples as well.

Note that you could also create an OptionSet (A Swift construct that lets you treat bit flags as if they are sets.) You could insert a value for each segmented control into your bit field, and then build your colors based on what options were set in the OptionSet without having to worry about the order like you are doing with tuples.

See this link for info on option sets: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-option-sets/

### EDIT:

Actually, after playing with it, I think @Alexander has the right idea with his suggestion to use enums. However, I would then create a set of enums so you can take advantage of the fact that sets are unordered and contain at most once of each possible value.

The code below defines a color enum, and then the function colorFromColorValue() returns a tuple with the color and it's name so you can display the name as wells as the color:

```
enum ColorValue: Int {
  case red = 0
  case yellow = 1
  case blue = 2
}

typealias ColorTuple = (name: String, color: UIColor?)

func colorFromColorValue(first: ColorValue?, second: ColorValue?) -> ColorTuple {
  
  guard let first = first,
    let second = second else {
      return ("Unknown", nil)
  }
  let aColor: Set<ColorValue> = [first, second]
  switch aColor {
  case [.red]:
    return ("Red", UIColor.red)
  case [.yellow]:
    return ("Yellow", UIColor.yellow)
  case [.blue]:
    return ("Blue", UIColor.blue)
  case [.red, .yellow]:
    return ("Orange", UIColor.orange)
  case [.red, .blue]:
    return ("Purple", UIColor.purple)
  case [.yellow, .blue]:
    return ("Green", UIColor.green)
  default:
    return ("Unknown", nil)
  }
}
```

You can then use that code in an IBAction method like this:

```
@IBAction func colorControlChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  let firstColor = ColorValue(rawValue: color1Control.selectedSegmentIndex)
  let secondColor = ColorValue(rawValue: color2Control.selectedSegmentIndex)
  let aColor = colorFromColorValue(first: firstColor,
                                   second: secondColor)
  if let color = aColor.color {
    colorView.backgroundColor = color
  } else {
    colorView.backgroundColor = .white
  }
  colorLabel.text = aColor.name
}
```